# z-index not working autocompleter under tabs

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with my autocompleter. If I resize my site then the autocompleter is under the tabs even I have z-index on it.
How can I fix this problem? I tried many things for example change the class autocompleter to absolute then it is over the tabs but the position changes. If I resize again to desktop size then it is not working.

[image]

Here is my css for the autocompleter:

```
.search_box{ float: left;position: relative;width:100%;}

.search-input-fields{float: left;width:100%; position: relative; }
.search-btn-wrap{float: left;width:100%;}

.search_box .search-input-fields input{float:left; height: auto; padding:12px 20px 12px; border-radius:0; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background-color:#ffffff; box-shadow: none; font-weight: 600; color:#000000; }
.search_box .search-input-fields select{float:left;  padding:12px 20px; border-radius:0; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; border-right:none; background-color:#ffffff; box-shadow: none; font-weight: 600; }

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  /* Chrome- and Safari-specific CSS here*/

.search_box .search-input-fields select{float:left; -webkit-appearance: none;

    background: url("/assets/fonts/selectdown.png") 96% / 15% no-repeat #eee; background-size:15px;  border-radius:0; border: 1px solid #eeeeee; background-color:#ffffff; box-shadow: none; font-weight: 600; }
}
.search_box .search-btn-wrap input[type="submit"]{
    width: 100%;border-radius:0;line-height: normal;padding-bottom: 10px;padding:14px;background-color: #ff5a5f;
    border:none;color: #ffffff;margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.search_box .location{ width:100%; float:left;position: relative;}


.search_box .guest{ width:100%; color:#909090}

.search_box select:disabled {
    background: #f5f5f5!important;
}

div.autocomplete {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
    left: 15px;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 100%;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 999999999!important;
}
.search_box .location div.autocomplete{
       left:0;
       right: 0;
}

.search_box .location ul.autocomplete li .glyphicon{
     display: block;
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 13px;
}

.search_box .location ul.autocomplete li{
    padding-left: 40px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 1.7;
}

.search_box .location span.search-close-icon{
    top:14px;
}
ul.autocomplete{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    /*border:1px solid #c4c4c4;*/
    margin:0;
}
ul.autocomplete li{border-top:1px solid #e6e6e6; padding:10px; line-height: 1; color: #999999;cursor: pointer }
ul.autocomplete li .bold{color:#333333; font-weight: 600;display:inline-block; vertical-align: top;  line-height: 1.7; }
ul.autocomplete li a{ text-decoration: none;color:inherit; }

ul.autocomplete li  .glyphicon { font-size: 20px; line-height: 1; margin-right: 10px; color:#999999;  }

ul.autocomplete li:hover{background-color:#00bce4;color:#ffffff;  }
ul.autocomplete li:hover a{ text-decoration: none }
ul.autocomplete li:hover .bold{ color: #ffffff; }
ul.autocomplete li:hover .glyphicon {color:#ffffff; }

.search-input-fields .col-sm-6,.search-input-fields .col-sm-3,.search-input-fields .col-sm-2, .search-input-fields .col-sm-4{
    position: initial; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 20px;border-right:1px;
}
.location-inner-wrap { float: left; position: relative; width: 100%; }
span.search-close-icon {
    color: #00bce4;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: auto;
    z-index: 999999;
}

/*.col-sm-4{padding-right:0!important;}*/
@media (max-width: 767px){

    .search-input-fields .col-sm-6,.search-input-fields .col-sm-3,.search-input-fields .col-sm-2, .search-input-fields .col-sm-4{float: left;width: 100%;position: relative; padding-right:15px; padding-left:15px; border-right:1px;}

    div.autocomplete {margin-top: 0; width:100%}
}
```

**Here is my css for tabs:**

```
.tabs-left>li:hover{
    border-bottom-color:transparent!important;
}

li.active span.round-tabs.one {
    background: #fff !important;
    border: 2px solid #8EC73F;
    color: #8EC73F;
    z-index:0;
}

li.active span.round-tabs.two {
    background: #fff !important;
    border: 2px solid #00bce4;
    color: #00bce4;
}

li.active span.round-tabs.three {
    background: #fff !important;
    border: 2px solid purple;
    color: purple;
}


.glyphicon-th:hover{
    color:#8EC73F;
}
.glyphicon-bullhorn:hover{
    color:#00bce4;
}
.login{
    margin-top:auto;
}

 span.round-tabs {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    line-height: 70px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
}

footer{
width:70%;

}
.text-muted{
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}

.glyphicon-filter{
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sticky" style="background-color:#F5F5F5;">
    <login (roleSet)='setRole($event)' (loginState)='loginState($event)' (userIdSet)='setUserId($event)' (refreshPage)='changeQuery(1)'
        [logoutFlag]='logoutFlag'></login>

    <div class="load" *ngIf="loading"></div>
    <div class="search" style=" background-color:#FFFFFF;">

        <div class="container-fluid " style=" background-color:#FFFFFF;">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 logo">

                </div>


                <div class="col-md-10 searchfilter">
                    <div class="form-section">
                        <div class="row">
                            <form id="searchfield">

                                <div class="search_box">

                                    <div class="search-input-fields">
                                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                            <div class="location">
                                                <div class="location-inner-wrap">
                                                    <input type="text" class="guest" [(ngModel)]="place_search" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (keyup)="search(place_search)"
                                                        placeholder="z.B. Berlin oder Ballonfahrt Berlin" focus="true">
                                                    <span class="search-close-icon"><i (click)="emptyAutocomplete()" class="search-close-icon glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="autocomplete">
                                                    <ul class="autocomplete">
                                                        <li *ngIf="noplacefound== true">No records found.</li>

                                                        <li *ngFor="let place of items" (click)="selectPlace(place)">

                                                            <i *ngIf="place.is_city== true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i>
                                                            <i *ngIf="place.is_city== false" class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i>
                                                            <span class="bold">{{place.placename}}</span> {{place.country}}

                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div  *ngIf="!toggleFilter">
                                        <div class="col-sm-2">

                                            <select [(ngModel)]="miles" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" class="miles_select guest" (change)="changeRange($event)">

                                                <option value="20">20 km</option>
                                                <option value="50">50 km</option>
                                                <option value="100">100 km </option>
                                                <option value="200">>200 km</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                                            <select class="guest categorydd" [(ngModel)]="category_search" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" (ngModelChange)="changeCategory($event)">

                                                <option value="Alle Kategorien" >Alle Kategorien</option>
                                                <option *ngFor="let x of countedCategory " value="{{x._id}}"> {{x._id}} ({{x.total}})</option>

                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="category_search == 'Alle Kategorien'">
                                            <select class="guest subcategorydd" [(ngModel)]="specCategory_search" name="specCategory_search" (ngModelChange)="changeSpecCat($event)">
                                                <option label="Unterkategorie" selected>Unterkategorie</option>
                                                <optgroup label="Fliegen &amp; Fallen" >
                                                        <option value="Fallen &amp; Springen">Fallen &amp; Springen</option>
                                                    <option value="Fliegen mit Motor">Fliegen mit Motor</option>
                                                    <option value="Gleiten &amp; Schweben">Gleiten &amp; Schweben</option>
                                                    <option value="Jets &amp; Weltraum">Jets &amp; Weltraum</option>
                                                </optgroup>

                                                <optgroup label="Motorpower">
                                                    <option value="Geländewagen">Geländewagen </option>
                                                    <option value="Ketten &amp; Schienen">Ketten &amp; Schienen</option>
                                                    <option value="Motorräder">Motorräder</option>
                                                    <option value="Oldtimer">Oldtimer </option>
                                                    <option value="Quads &amp; Spaßmobile">Quads &amp; Spaßmobile </option>
                                                    <option value="Rennwagen">Rennwagen</option>
                                                    <option value="Schneefahrzeuge">Schneefahrzeuge</option>
                                                    <option value="Traumautos">Traumautos </option>

                                                </optgroup>

                                                <optgroup label="Essen &amp; Trinken">
                                                    <option value="Essen gehen">Essen gehen</option>
                                                    <option value="Kochkurse">Kochkurse</option>
                                                    <option value="Wein, Bier &amp; Spirituosen">Wein, Bier &amp; Spirituosen</option>
                                                    <option value="Kaffee &amp; Schokolade">Kaffee &amp; Schokolade</option>
                                                </optgroup>

                                                <optgroup label="Abenteuer &amp; Sport">
                                                    <option value="Sport im Sommer">Sport im Sommer</option>
                                                    <option value="Sport im Winter">Sport im Winter</option>
                                                    <option value="Action &amp; Stunts">Action &amp; Stunts</option>
                                                    <option value="Wildnis">Wildnis</option>

                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="Wellness &amp; Gesundheit">
                                                    <option value="Verwöhnen &amp; Erholen">Verwöhnen &amp; Erholen</option>
                                                    <option value="Beauty &amp; Styling">Beauty &amp; Styling</option>
                                                    <option value="Fitness &amp; Ernährung">Fitness &amp; Ernährung</option>
                                                    <option value="Körper &amp; Seele">Körper &amp; Seele</option>

                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="Kunst, Kultur &amp; Lifestyle">
                                                    <option value="Dating, Liebe &amp; Romantik">Dating, Liebe &amp; Romantik</option>
                                                    <option value="Kunst &amp; Handwerk">Kunst &amp; Handwerk</option>
                                                    <option value="Lifestyle">Lifestyle</option>
                                                    <option value="Musik &amp; Tanz">Musik &amp; Tanz</option>
                                                    <option value="Vor der Kamera">Vor der Kamera</option>
                                                    <option value="Vor der Kamera">Wedding</option>

                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="Wasser &amp; Wind">
                                                    <option value="Boot">Boot</option>
                                                    <option value="Kajak">Kanu</option>
                                                    <option value="Rafting">Rafting</option>
                                                    <option value="Segeln">Segeln</option>
                                                    <option value="Surfen">Surfen</option>
                                                    <option value="Tauchen">Tauchen</option>
                                                    <option value="Wasserspass">Wasserspass</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="Reisen">


                                                    <!-- <option value="Festivals">Festival</option> -->
                                                    <option value="Alpin">Alpin</option>
                                                    <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
                                                    <option value="Kultur">Kultur</option>
                                                    <!-- <option value="Nachtleben">Nachtleben</option> -->
                                                    <option value="Romantik">Romantik</option>
                                                    <option value="Staedtetrips &amp; Ausfluege">Staedtetrips &amp; Ausfluege</option>
                                                </optgroup>

                                            </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="category_search == 'Fliegen &amp; Fallen'">

                                            <select class="guest subcategorydd" [(ngModel)]="specCategory_search" name="specCategory_search" (ngModelChange)="changeSpecCat($event)">

                                                <optgroup label="Fliegen &amp; Fallen">
                                                    <option value="Fallen &amp; Springen">Fallen &amp; Springen</option>
                                                    <option value="Fliegen mit Motor">Fliegen mit Motor</option>
                                                    <option value="Gleiten &amp; Schweben">Gleiten &amp; Schweben</option>
                                                    <option value="Jets &amp; Weltraum">Jets &amp; Weltraum</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="category_search == 'Motorpower'">

                                            <select id="scrollable-menu" class="guest subcategorydd" [(ngModel)]="specCategory_search" name="specCategory_search" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
                                                (ngModelChange)="changeSpecCat($event)">
                                                <optgroup label="Motorpower">
                                                    <option value="Geländewagen">Geländewagen </option>
                                                    <option value="Ketten &amp; Schienen">Ketten &amp; Schienen</option>
                                                    <option value="Motorräder">Motorräder</option>
                                                    <option value="Oldtimer">Oldtimer </option>
                                                    <option value="Quads &amp; Spaßmobile">Quads &amp; Spaßmobile </option>
                                                    <option value="Rennwagen">Rennwagen</option>
                                                    <option value="Schneefahrzeuge">Schneefahrzeuge</option>
                                                    <option value="Traumautos">Traumautos </option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="category_search == 'Essen &amp; Trinken'">

                                            <select id="scrollable-menu" class="guest subcategorydd" [(ngModel)]="specCategory_search" name="specCategory_search" (ngModelChange)="changeSpecCat($event)">
                                                <optgroup label="Essen &amp; Trinken">
                                                    <option value="Essen gehen">Essen gehen</option>
                                                    <option value="Kochkurse">Kochkurse</option>
                                                    <option value="Wein, Bier &amp; Spirituosen">Wein, Bier &amp; Spirituosen</option>
                                                    <option value="Kaffee &amp; Schokolade">Kaffee &amp; Schokolade</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="category_search == 'Abenteuer &amp; Sport'">

                                            <select class="guest subcategorydd" [(ngModel)]="specCategory_search" name="specCategory_search" (ngModelChange)="changeSpecCat($event)">
                                                <optgroup label="Abenteuer &amp; Sport">
                                                    <option value="Sport im Sommer">Sport im Sommer</option>
                                                    <option value="Sport im Winter">Sport im Winter</option>
                                                    <option value="Action &amp; Stunts">Action &amp; Stunts</option>
                                                    <option value="Wildnis">Wildnis</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="category_search == 'Wellness &amp; Gesundheit'">

                                            <select class="guest subcategorydd" [(ngModel)]="specCategory_search" name="specCategory_search" (ngModelChange)="changeSpecCat($event)">
                                                <optgroup label="Wellness &amp; Gesundheit">
                                                    <option value="Beauty & Styling">Beauty & Styling</option>
                                                    <option value="Massagen">Massagen</option>
                                                    <option value="Verwöhnen &amp; Erholen">Verwöhnen &amp; Erholen</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="category_search == 'Kunst, Kultur &amp; Lifestyle'">

                                            <select class="guest subcategorydd" [(ngModel)]="specCategory_search" name="specCategory_search" (ngModelChange)="changeSpecCat($event)">
                                                <optgroup label="Kunst, Kultur &amp; Lifestyle">
                                                    <option value="Vor der Kamera">Vor der Kamera</option>
                                                    <option value="Kunst &amp; Handwerk">Kunst &amp; Handwerk</option>
                                                    <option value="Musik &amp; Tanz">Musik &amp; Tanz</option>
                                                    <option value="Dating, Liebe &amp; Romantik">Dating, Liebe &amp; Romantik</option>
                                                    <option value="Lifestyle">Lifestyle</option>

                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="category_search == 'Wasser &amp; Wind'">

                                            <select class="guest subcategorydd" [(ngModel)]="specCategory_search" name="specCategory_search" (ngModelChange)="changeSpecCat($event)">
                                                <optgroup label="Wasser &amp; Wind">
                                                    <option value="Boot">Boot</option>
                                                    <option value="Kajak">Kajak</option>
                                                    <option value="Kanu">Kanu</option>
                                                    <option value="Rafting">Rafting</option>
                                                    <option value="Segeln">Segeln</option>
                                                    <option value="Surfen">Surfen</option>
                                                    <option value="Tauchen">Tauchen</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-3" *ngIf="category_search == 'Reisen'">
                                            <select class="guest subcategorydd" [(ngModel)]="specCategory_search" name="specCategory_search" (ngModelChange)="changeSpecCat($event)">
                                                <optgroup label="Reisen">

                                                    <option value="Alpin">Alpin</option>
                                                    <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
                                                    <option value="Kultur">Kultur</option>
                                                    <!-- <option value="Nachtleben">Nachtleben</option> -->
                                                    <option value="Romantik">Romantik</option>
                                                    <option value="Staedtetrips &amp; Ausfluege">Staedtetrips &amp; Ausfluege</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
</div>

                                    </div>


                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter" (click)="toggleFilter = !toggleFilter" ></i>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid ">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="tabbable-panel">
                <div class="tabbable-line">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left">
                        <li class="active">
                            <a href="#_all" data-toggle="tab" (click)="pricewise(0)"> 
                                <span class="round-tabs one">
                              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i>
                      </span>

                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#_all" (click)="loadNewsComment(); messageTab=false;loadingFeeds()" data-toggle="tab" >
                                        <span class="round-tabs two">
                              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-bullhorn"></i>
                      </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#_own" data-toggle="tab" style="outline:none;" (click)="getOwn()" *ngIf="role ==1"> Eigene </a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#_all" style="outline:none;" (click)="messageClick()" *ngIf="isAlive" data-toggle="tab"> 
                                    <span class="round-tabs three">
                              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                      </span>
                            </a>
                        </li>



                    </ul>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the html?!??!?!
can you provide it in jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and add a z-index to .search_box

Something like z-index 50 to test (reduce this z-index to a logic in your website after)

Also check the opacity

Comment: Ok my mistake. I had an opacity of 0.9 for the class searchfilter

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

add z-index to search-box
.search_box{z-index:100 float: left;position: relative;width:100%;}